# Cohen calculation in R

Tags: r

For a reproducibility analysis, I have to calculate the Cohen's d of a multiple regression in R. 
However I did nog find any possibility for doing that. When I compute the linear regression, I get a R^2 from R but no Cohen's D. 
I already tried the effsize package, however it does not seem to work with my formula.

Here is my script for the regression:

```
lr_watchweek <- lm(mwb ~ watch_wd + (I(watch_wd^2)), data = new_data)
summary(lr_watchweek)
```

From this linear regression I need to compute the Cohen's d, how is this possible in R?

Comment: Probably will need to be more specific about what you're trying to calculate.  Cohen's D for the coefficient estimates?  "effect size" of the marginal change in an independent variable?

Comment: What didn't work with `effsize`? A reproducible example will go along way to getting a solution. Also, why not calculate it yourself it seems quite straight forward: `mean diff / pooled sd`

Comment: Your problem is more with stats than programming. If you can't find an answer here you might have more luck on CrossValidated: https://stats.stackexchange.com/